# Difference between JSPX and JSFF file-types inside ADF framework?

Tags: jsp, jsf, file-type, oracle-adf, jsp-fragments

What is the difference between JSPF and JSFF file-types in ADF ?

I have not been able to find sufficient information on JSFF files online.

JSPX and JSFF refer to JSP Fragment and JSF Fragment respectively. JSFF is typically used in ADF projects.

Answer (score 12):

JSFF is used for page fragments in ADF
JSPX is used for regular JSF pages

You can have JSFF inside ADF taskflows and then include them inside JSPX pages.

Comment: I have an adf taskflow with jsff's inside, but when i drag it into a jspx file it gives an error saying 'Cannot create a region from a task flow containing facelets fragments in a jspx page. '

Answer (score 9):

jsff is not a runnable target If you want to run this page It should be included inside jspx pages.
One more major thing is that, whenever we use ADF task flow we use jsff fragment

OR You can Say that:--

**.jspx** page is **JSP/XML** representation, it is a standalone page which means it can run without any supporting or base page. Jdeveloper 11g Release1 supports .jspx page but this is not in Jdeveloper 11g Release2, Release2 supports Facelets means .jsf (**Be clear that .jsf and .jsff is not the same thing**).

**while**

**.jsff** (JSF fragments) page is a fragment of JSF(Java Server Faces) page, sometimes pages become too much complex and large and it is not easy to edit those pages, in that case it should be divided in some fragments. JSF page can be broken in some smaller page fragments to avoid difficulties in editing and maintaining page fragments **can't run independently,** it requires a base of **.jsf(JSF page)** or **.jspx (JSP/XML)** page

**Note:-** (**.jsf and .jsff is not the same thing**)

**.jsf Vs .jspx**

1. jspx is by convention, a JSP/XML representation, whereas .jsf is by convention a facelets representation. Neither is "more compatible," but Facelets is the recommended way forward, as long as you are on 11.1.2 or later.
2. 11.1.2.x uses .jsf as default (for Faclets) where as 11.1.1.x uses .jspx
3. Usually Facelets is considered to be of better performance because it is tighter integrated with the JSf lifcycle and doesn't need to be compiled before running it
4. JSPX documents and Facelets are bot supported with JDeveloper 11g R2 and we do support them equallly in functionality (very little differences exist on both sides)
5. JSPX documents are the only choice in JDeveloper 11g R1

Answer (score 2):

JSFF is used for page fragments while JSPX is used for regular ADF pages, technically you can also use JSPX as page fragment. When you use JDeveloper wizard to create a page fragment, the default extension will be jsff.

According to the Oracle document "there is no special reason to use .jsff other than quick differentiation between complete JSF pages and page fragments when you are working in the Application Navigator in JDeveloper."